# Under what conditions is the delegate method pictureInPictureControllerWillStopPictureInPicture called?

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, picture-in-picture

I have developed a sample ios application using `AVPlayer` as an underlying framework. I have successfully implemented picture in picture playback using `AVPictureInPictureController` as well.

But the problem arises, when I switch to the next content in the playlist after the initial content finishes playing in `PictureInPictureMode`. At this point, the player automatically switches to the full screen mode and the delegate method : `pictureInPictureControllerWillStopPictureInPicture` is called.

I want the next content to continue playing in PIP mode. 
Can anyone tell me under what conditions, the delegate method:`pictureInPictureControllerWillStopPictureInPicture` is called.

Comment: why don't you show us code where you have don't this ?

Comment: I am afraid I cannot share the code.Its confidential. However the property isPictureInPictureProperty is set to false when this happens.

Comment: of course you need to do it true.

Comment: This property is not writeable.